# Determining a user's general employment status

Tags: html, security, verification

I'm developing a web application for people who manage nonprofit organizations. This will require me to verify that certain users belong to a nonprofit. Here are a few verification methods I've considered:

- Verifying the user's location through JavaScript's Geolocation API.
- Maintaining a list of nonprofit domains and requiring that the user's email matches one of the domains.
- Sending a physical letter to a business address.
- Soliciting a phone number and calling the users to confirm their employment status.

None of these methods seem to be efficient or scalable. The first method may provide an extra little layer of security, but users can easily spoof geolocation. Is there a better way to accomplish this type of verification?

Comment: Programatically?  Not really.

Comment: Agree with Oli. #2 doesn't seem like an unreasonable amount of effort.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. One thing I'm curious about is Twitter's verification process. Despite having millions of users (and many celebrity accounts), they are able to determine a user's employment status.